# revert back to stft from abs and phase

Tags: python, spectrogram, stft

I have the following code on python

```
stftspectro = librosa.stft(audio, n_fft=fft_length, hop_length=stride, win_length=window, window='hann')
abs = np.abs(stftspectro)
angle = np.angle(stftspectro)
```

Can i revert back to stftspectro from below abs and angle. I have no knowledge about sound signals but spectogram from `stft` is great for audio properties as i have read, and i am applying some deep neural networks that rely on such features.
Moreover, doing the inverse stft will produce the same sound:

```
stfttoaudio = librosa.istft(stftspectro, hop_length=stride, win_length=window, window='hann')
```

so collecting both abs and angle is helpful in my thought.

Comment: This is just a question about complex numbers. Yes, any complex number can be represented as magnitude (abs) and angle, see *Euler's formula* – that's pretty fundamental math that you should really understand if you're dealing with Fourier transforms!

Comment: i tried to implement `convstft = abs*np.cos(angle)+1j*np.sin(angle)` but it didn't match stftspectro variable @MarcusMüller

Comment: um, your formula is wrong: operator precedence of `*` over `+`!

Answer (score 2):

As Marcus Müller said, there is an error, when converting `abs` and `angle` values back to complex numbers. It should be like this:

\begin{align}
x = |x|(\cos \phi + j \sin\phi)
\end{align}

Note, that the result `convstft` of this conversion will be close, but not equal to the original values in `stftspectro`, most probably, due to inaccuracy of floating point computations.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
import librosa

# Creating some audio signal
y, sr = librosa.load(librosa.ex('choice'), duration=10)
tempo, beats = librosa.beat.beat_track(y=y, sr=sr)
audio = librosa.clicks(frames=beats, sr=sr)

# Applying short-time Fourier transform with default parameters
fft_length = 2048
stride = 2048 // 4
window = 2048

stftspectro = librosa.stft(audio, n_fft=fft_length, hop_length=stride, win_length=window, window='hann')
abs_val = np.abs(stftspectro)
angle = np.angle(stftspectro)

# Converting abs and angle back to complex number
convstft = abs_val*(np.cos(angle)+1j*np.sin(angle))

# Checking results
# Choosing an arbitrary element index
n=50
m=45

# Is this element similar?
print("stftspectro element:",stftspectro[n][m])
print("abs_val element:",abs_val[n][m])
print("angle element:",angle[n][m])
print("convstft element:",convstft[n][m])

# Are stftspectro and convstft the same?
A=stftspectro
B=convstft
eps = 0.0001+1j*0.0001
print("Are they similar: ",np.array_equal(A,B))  # test if same shape, same elements values
print("Are they close: ",np.allclose(A,B,atol=eps)) # test if same shape, elements have close enough values
```

Also, I wouldn't use `abs` as a name for a variable, since it's the name of the python method abs().